# Is it possible a one click user registration with Facebook or Twitter (or other Social Networks)?

Tags: login, facebook, twitter, authentication, user-registration

Would it be possible to create a wp user by signin up with Facebook connect? (And through Twitter app, and eventually other major social networks? Facebook is most important, then Twitter, the rest are not so important) - User fills form with one click, eventually is asked in the form to fill a custom display name (otherwise defaults to Facebook user name / Twitter user etc).

I'm a bit confused whether this is achievable or not. Certain plugins seem to allow user publication of comments without registering, but what I really want is to create a normal WP user (also because on my WP site I have a BB Press forum, plus Gravity form modules, so it's not just a blog, I have a complex CMS setup). Is there an existing plugin (even commercial, not free) that does exactly what I want?

Furthermore, I would like to make this happen on custom registration/login forms, I do not wish to use the default wp-register and wp-login pages at all.

I have tried Simple Facebook connect and  Simple Twitter connect, but they do not work on custom login/registration pages and I haven't figured how to make them work there.

As for Gigya and JainRain I haven't understood if they actually create a user or just create a login. Can someone clarify?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin ['Social Login for WordPress'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/) which serves the functions you are looking for. This plugin not only allows users to log in but also creates users on your website and auto-fill various fields in registration form.

The plugin is FREE but there are white label and customized solutions available from [LoginRadius](http://www.loginradius.com).

Comment: mmm Social Login looks like it only grants authentication to users registered to external services, while I would also be able to create a user when they login with such services; the only plugin that seems to do this is Simple Facebook Connect which uses the user registration tool from Facebook; the others seem not to create a User in WP database - thanks for your answer anyway